# Iterate S3 folder to get recent files as per 'last_modified_date'

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Iterate S3 folder to get to get recent files as per '`last_modified_date`'.

We have a S3 bucket having folder structure as below (data coming on hourly basis):

> **s3://my_bucket/stream/yy/mm/dd/hh:**

examples:

```
s3://my_bucket/stream/2019/01/01/00
s3://my_bucket/stream/2019/01/01/01
s3://my_bucket/stream/2019/01/01/02
:
:
s3://my_bucket/stream/2019/01/02/00
s3://my_bucket/stream/2019/01/02/01
```

I need to iterate the files in the S3 bucket in the order of last modified date using AWS Lambda.

Has anyone done it before? Appreciate your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "iterate folders with recent files upload as per last modified date"? What do you actually want to do? What problems are you currently experiencing?

Comment: You could use the S3 events in order to notify your Lambda that a new file has been arrived.